# Always redirect current user to certain page

Tags: redirect

What code do i have to use to always redirect a certain user (or role) to a certain page?

***Example:**
IF Logged in & current user = Harry **Then** Redirect to domain.com/harryspage
IF Logged in & current user = Carl **Then** Redirect to domain.com/carlspage

or

**IF** Logged in & current role = Harry **Then** Redirect to domain.com/harryspage
*IF* Logged in & current role = Carl **Then** Redirect to domain.com/carlspage

**I found this code, but its used for some plugin that i dont want to use. Could this be rebuild the way i want it to work?:**

Comment: I found this code: <?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_front_page() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $url = wpum_get_profile_url( $current_user );
        wp_redirect( $url ); 
        exit;
    }
}